# C#/Silverlight: I want to pass a variable that I want to use in the async callback function

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Ok I am using the HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse and I pass in the async callback function, now I want to pass in a variable/context as well that I want to my callback function to get. How do I do this. I am fairly new to the C#/.Net/Silverlight world.

```
 HttpWebRequest absRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlToFetch));
        absRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(onABSFetchComplete), absRequest);
```

here my objective is in the above call I want to pass a variable and I want my callback to get called with that variable. 
thanks!

Comment: How can i achieve the functionality in C#.NET alone without ASP.NET (like httpWebRequest...etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use a lambda expression. Something like this:

```
absRequest.BeginGetResponse(result => OnFetchComplete(result, foo, absRequest),
                            null);
```

where `OnFetchComplete` now has the signature you *really* want (with the extra parameters - in this case one corresponding to `foo`) rather than just an `IASyncResult`. You no longer need to give `absRequest` as the "context" for the `IAsyncResult`, as you're capturing it in the lambda expression.

If you're not familiar with lambda expressions though, you should really take time to get to grips with them though - not just for this, but for LINQ and all kinds of other purposes.

Comment: thanks a  lot that solution worked and I sure will read up on this.

Comment: How can i achieve the functionality in C#.NET alone without ASP.NET (like httpWebRequest...etc.)?

Comment: @sukumar: HttpWebRequest has BeginGetResponse already. That's not part of ASP.NET.